# click on button which have values from array or list

Tags: java, selenium, katalon-studio

I have a list of dropdown predefine values from the web site as below

```
"KSA", "UAE", "Bahrain", "Oman", "Qatar", "Kuwait","Egypt","Jordan", "Tunisia" , "Morocco", "Palestine","Iraq"
```

need a helping  selenium/  katalon code for click on those values

Comment: so write it. you want us to a) guess what all the id's are you used in your code and b) do your work for you?

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Paste your HTML code ?

Comment: <li class="header__country-selector--desktop__country">
 <a href="/change-country?to=ae&amp;url=/news/3479291/Saudi-Arabia-to-introduce-new-residency-scheme-for-expatriates">UAE</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="header__country-selector--desktop__country">
                      <a href="/change-country?to=bh&amp;url=/news/3479291/Saudi-Arabia-to-introduce-new-residency-scheme-for-expatriates">Bahrain</a>

Comment: 1) Tip: Add @Stultuske (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment. 2) Please [edit] the question to add further information. 3) Be sure to use code formatting for code and code snippets, structured documents like **HTML/XML** or input/output.  To do that, select the text and click the `{}` button at the top of the message posting/editing form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the countries in a list and if the dropdown is a select element, you can use the following code to select, for example "KSA":

```
def countries = ["KSA", "UAE", "Bahrain", "Oman", "Qatar", "Kuwait","Egypt","Jordan", "Tunisia" , "Morocco", "Palestine","Iraq"]
WebUI.click(findTestObject('dropdown-element'))
WebUI.selectOptionByValue(findTestObject('dropdown-element'), countries[0], false)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using c#, then try this

```
        IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        IList<IWebElement> dropdownLists = driver.FindElements(By.Id("yourdropdown"));
        foreach (IWebElement item in dropdownLists)
        {
            if (item.Text.Equals("KSA"))
            {
                item.Click();
            }

            //if(item.Text.Equals("UAE")) ..... etc
        }
```

you can also use a switch condition to select your place within the foreach statement